# How can I perform a cookie check on login and navigation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a component header, and in it I make a cookie selection to show one icon or another, but when logging in and changing pages the cookie check is not redone. I cannot be using useState or useEffect, as it is a NextJS project, where in the file I use next/headers. Here's the code:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { ModeToggle } from "./mode-toggle";
import { LogOut, User2 } from "lucide-react";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default function Header() {
    const isAuthenticated = cookies().has('token')

    return (
        <header className='flex justify-between py-6 px-10 border-b-2 items-center'>
            <h1 className='font-title text-2xl'><Link href={'/'}>.upnews</Link></h1>
            <div className="flex gap-5 items-center">
                <ModeToggle />
                <div className="border p-1.5 rounded-md hover:bg-secondary cursor-pointer">
                    {
                        isAuthenticated ? <Link href={'/api/auth/logout'}><LogOut size={22} /></Link> : <Link href={'/account/login'}><User2 size={22} /></Link>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    )
}
```

When changing pages and reloading the page with F5, the icon changes.

Comment: Well [`cookies`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) is documented to work only in server components.